# Can I use healpy to stack sky?

Tags: astronomy, healpy

I would like to stack WMAP maps at the locations of galaxies. Is it possible to perform this using healpy? Which function in healpy allows me to get a projection of the sky around a point?
thanks

Comment: which type of projections? can you provide a minimal example of what you want to achieve (with small arrays)?

Answer (score 1):

with `gnomview` you can specify the central point with `rot`, then set `return_projected_map=True` to get a 2D array of the projected map back.